# Extracting singularity or stiff point from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

Given the coupled non-linear differential equations:

```
a = 0;
k = 10^(11);
q[y_] = (a Sqrt[k](Tanh[y/Sqrt[k]])^2)/(1+a^2 (Tanh[y/Sqrt[k]])^2)
Eq1[y_]:= h[y]*h''[y]-2h'[y]h[y] f'[y]-2(h[y])^4(x[y])^2+
(A'[y])^2/2+2q[y]^2(x[y]^2)(A[y])^2;
Eq2[y_]:= h[y]*h''[y]-2(h[y])^2 f''[y]+2(h[y])^2(x'[y])^2+(A'[y])^2/2;
Eq3[y_]:= x''[y]*h[y]+h'[y] x'[y]-2*x'[y]*h[y]*f'[y] - h[y]*(h[y]^2 -2+(A[y])^2((q[y]/(h[y]))^2+1))*x[y];
Eq4[y_]:= h[y]*A''[y]-h'[y]*A'[y]-2f'[y]*h[y]*A'[y]-4*A[y]*x[y]^2*h[y](q[y]^2+(h[y])^2);
```

With the following boundary conditions:

```
ampc = Exp[-EulerGamma/2];
amp = ampc+1*10^(-3)+2*10^(-4); 
BC[k_,y1_]:={h[y1]==(Sqrt[k]Tanh[y1/Sqrt[k]])/(1+a^2(Tanh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2),h'[y1]==(a^2-(a^2-1)*(Cosh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2)/(((a^2+1)(Cosh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2-a^2)^2),
f[y1]==-2-0.5*Log[1+(1+a^2)*(Sinh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2],f'[y1]==((a^2+1)*Sinh[2*y1/Sqrt[k]])/(Sqrt[k]*(a^2-1-(a^2+1)*Cosh[2*y1/Sqrt[k]])),
x[y1]==amp*Exp[-( (y1^2)/2 )],x'[y1]==-amp* y1*Exp[-( (y1^2)/2 )],
A[y1]== (Sqrt[2*k]*a*(Tanh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2)/(1+a^2*(Tanh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2), A'[y1]== 2*Sqrt[2]*a*((Sech[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2*(Tanh[y1/Sqrt[k]]))/(1+a^2*(Tanh[y1/Sqrt[k]])^2)^2} ;
```

Using NDSolve I will evaluate the solutions numerically:

```
y1 = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{Eq1[y]==0,Eq2[y]==0,Eq3[y]==0,Eq4[y]==0,BC[k,y1][[1]],BC[k,y1][[2]],BC[k,y1][[3]],BC[k,y1][[4]],BC[k,y1][[5]],BC[k,y1][[6]],BC[k,y1][[7]],BC[k,y1][[8]]},
{h,f,x,A},{y,y1,-5},MaxSteps-> 100000, PrecisionGoal->60,WorkingPrecision->70,AccuracyGoal->50,Method->"StiffnessSwitching"]
```

The following output is appearing:

```
   NDSolve::ndsz: At y == -1.682978757491205806001350948676117564121113238846169811698291756357437, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

How to extract this value and put it at some variable? for my case:

```
ystiff =-1.682978757491205806001350948676117564121113238846169811698291756357437
```